# Xbox One + Skype = Echo on other side

Tags: xbox-one, skype

We have an Xbox One in our conference room that we use for Skype.

The TV is on the far wall, and the sound comes out of the TV.  We have a [Blue Yeti](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002VA464S) microphone sitting in the middle of the conference table, about 6 feet from the TV.

I tested this setup by placing a call from my laptop, in a different room away from the conference room.

I could hear the conversation in the conference room great, but when I spoke, I could hear my own voice, slightly delayed.  This echo is very disruptive.

I suspect that what is happening is that my voice comes out of the TV in the conf room, and the Blue Yeti mic pics it up and sends it back over the connection.

Is there a way to configure the Xbox, my laptop, or the microphone to eliminate this echo?

Comment: What pattern is the blue yeti on? Make sure it's the front mic only  (cardioid I believe) and that its gain isn't too high. I should also point out that unfortunately this question seems to be off topic as it's not about gaming...

Comment: You could also turn down the volume on the TV

Comment: @Batophobia:  That's how we hear the other side.

Comment: @Rapitor:  I took a look at that, and what I found is that the XB1 is not using the Yeti mic -- it's still using the Kinect mic.  I have still not been able to enable the Yeti USB mic and turn off the Kinect mic.

Comment: Pretty certain the Xbox One doesn't even support third party mics now that I think about it. Like 90% certain. You can however [Calibrate the Kinect](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/kinect/microphone-calibration) So it listens better and ignores the tv a bit more.

Comment: This might be obvious but, was your Kinect enabled for chat?

Comment: @EricTobias:  We tried it both ways.

Comment: Try reducing the volume of the TV or moving the microphone further away. If the volume does no longer pass the threshold the microphone will not send. Experiment with it and if the echo disappears your microphone was the culprit. In that case you are out of luck. Usually noise cancelling will take care of echo but, obviously, it does not seem to work with the brand of microphone you are using.

Comment: @EricTobias:  But we became convinced that the add-on mic was not even being used.  We couldn't find any settings regarding noise cancellation on the kinect microphone.  Are there any such settings?

Comment: No, there is no setting. When the Kinect is set up (you did that, didn't you?) It uses sound emitted by the speakers to scan the room and set up the audio environment. Then, custom hardware/software does the actual noise cancelling. As it is a delicate process, it is not configurable and always on by default on the Kinect. If you use a custom microphone, there is no noise cancelling. Sources: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rYF9kpZ5xqs and http://www.reddit.com/r/xboxone/comments/1rf7r8/did_you_know_kinect_tv_noise_cancel/